# Is there a way to replace all occurrences of a string in a variable of a list?

Tags: java

I have a list as follows

```
List<Summary> summary;

Summary {
    int key;
    String value1;
    String value2;
}
```

Is there a way in java (or any other utility library) to replace all occurrences of a String "String1" in the variable value1 without having to loop through the list?

Comment: Is the position for the value "String1" is always in the exact position? Which I mean is, `summary.get(0).getValue1() --> "String1"`

Comment: it could be in multiple places ... i.e. summary.get(1), summary.get(5) etc.. its a list that is loaded from a database.

Comment: Than you can use loop, is there any reason you didn't want to use loop?

Comment: @Crazenezz - just trying to find out if there is a more optimal way to do this.

Comment: I have example on my answer, still using loop but what is my idea is you can create own library based on your needs.

Answer (score 7):

Looping the list is inevitable so you or some third party library has to do the looping. Is it really that hard to do:

```
for (Summary s : summary)
    if (s.value1.equals("String1"))
        s.value1 = "...";
```

? :)

Comment: its not about being hard to do. Whether there a more optimal implementation of it is what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: If that was the question you could have asked that from the start.. I think this is optimal! :)

Comment: @ArvindSridharan Using a loop(s) is often the most optimial solution in Java. IMHO you should assume a loop is the most optimal unless you know otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use a library that allow you use it without loops, the problem is that in the low level the compiler must use something like a loop for do it. 
I think that direct or indirectly you will use a loop.

So, for this reason you haven´t any problem if use a loop in your code.

Sorry for my English, I hope you can understand all.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method to find by the object part:

```
public class ListOfString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
            Model model = new Model();
            model.setStr("String"+i);
            models.add(model);
        }

        Model temp = new Model();
        temp.setStr("String1");

        System.out.println(containsObjectPart(temp, models));
    }

    // This method just a prototype, you can modify as you like...
    private static boolean containsObjectPart(Model obj, List<Model> models) {
        for(Model model : models) {
            if(model.getStr().equals(obj.getStr()))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}

class Model {

    private String str;

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot, `Loop` is `invetible`.But you can optimize it many area like, `selecting loop`, `how do you find the string and replacing it` .etc....

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid a bit of looping - at the expense of losing your list ordering - by using a `TreeSet`, with `value1` values as keys and the `Summary` objects as values. Then you can do a binary chop search to find all matching entries. A collection which uses hashing would have similar trade-offs and gains.

Otherwise, as everyone else has said, looping is inevitable. The only optimisation you could make is counting the entries as they go into the list so you know when you've found them all so you can stop looping.

But remember, [premature optimisation is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). :)