# Differences between 2 objects in java

Tags: java

I want to write a java program which has to find the differences between the two objects which is of different instances. I have implemented it using equals() and comparator. But here I want to find differences and have to show that in logging format.

My program is below :

```
public class A implements Comparator<A>{

private int id1, id2;

/* setters and getters for id1 and id2 */

     public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
    if (this.getClass() != arg0.getClass()) {
        return false;
        }

        if (((A) arg0).getId1() == this.id1 && ((A) arg0).getId2() == this.id2) {
        return true;
        }

        return false;
     }

 public static void main(String args[]) {

    A obj1 = new A();
    obj1.id1 = 10;
    obj1.id2 = 20;

    A obj2 = new A();
    obj2.id1 = 30;
    obj2.id2 = 20;

    /*
     * equals comparison
     */

    if (obj1.equals(obj2)) {
        System.out.println("EQUALS");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NOT EQUALS");
    }

}
```

Please can any body advise me how i can find the differences and show that in logging format.

Thanks.

Comment: For each property, compare. For each difference, log. It may be easier to generate a List<String> (or List<Object>) of the value, and then use a generalized comparator for each element or, use List<KeyValuePair<String,String>> (or Map<String,Object> or whatnot) to also include the property information, etc.

Comment: Do you want to compare all the property for each object or compare if the object is different instance? If you want to compare each the property try this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927781/is-there-a-way-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-variable-of-a-list/10928498#10928498) if you want to do the second one try using `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement `Comparator<A>` you need a method `public int compare(A o1, A o2)`. This is an example of such an implementation:

```
@Override
public int compare(A o1, A o2) {
    if (o1 == o2) {
        return 0;
    } else if (o1 == null) {
        return -1;
    } else if (o2 == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (o1.getId1() != o2.getId1()) {
        return o1.getId1() - o2.getId1();
    } else {
        return o1.getId2() - o2.getId2();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
    if (obj1.compare(obj1, obj2) == 0) {
        System.out.println("EQUALS");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NOT EQUALS");
    }
```

It is probably more common to make another class implement the `Comparator<A>`, instead of putting this in `A` itself.

Comment: I think that you are referring to the `compareTo` method.

Comment: No, that would be in the `Comparable<A>` interface

Comment: Indeed you are correct. I have never seen this method before. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use java `Reflection` to compare two same type beans those have getter for all comparing properties.

```
public static void compareBeans(Object bean1, Object bean2, String... propertyNames)
          throws IntrospectionException,
          IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>(Arrays
            .asList(propertyNames));
        BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean1
            .getClass());
        for (PropertyDescriptor prop : beanInfo
            .getPropertyDescriptors()) {
          if (names.remove(prop.getName())) {
            Method getter = prop.getReadMethod();
            Object value1 = getter.invoke(bean1);
            Object value2 = getter.invoke(bean2);
            if (value1 == value2
                || (value1 != null && value1.equals(value2))) {
              continue;
            }

            System.out.println("Property = "+prop.getName() +" Value of been1 ="+value1 +" : Value of bean2 ="+value2);
          }
        }
      }
```

**Usage:**

If i compare two beans of `Student` class which has two properties `name` and `age` like

```
BeanComparator.compareBeans(new Student("Amita", 21), new Student("Amit", 23) , props);
```

**Output:**

```
Property = age Value of been1 =21 : Value of bean2 =23
Property = name Value of been1 =Amita : Value of bean2 =Amit
```

Comment: Will it work with child objects also? For eg, if Students have list of address then will it be able to compare them also?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `equals` method and you compare each property. For each comparison you make, you log your result. Something like so should work:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
    if (this.getClass() != arg0.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    boolean same = true;
    //LOG: Comparing ((A) arg0).getId1() with this.id1
    if (((A) arg0).getId1() == this.id1) {
        //LOG: Property Id1 is the same for both: Value of Id1 = this.id1        
    }
    else {
        //LOG: Property Id1 is not the same. Source Id1 = ((A) arg0).getId1() , target Id1 = this.id1
        same = false;
    }

    if (((A) arg0).getId2() == this.id2) {
        //LOG: Property Id2 is the same for both: Value of Id2 = this.id2        
    }

    else {
        //LOG: Property Id2 is not the same. Source Id2 = (((A) arg0).getId2(), target Id2 = this.id2
        same = false;
    }

    //
    return same;
}
```

EDIT: I do not exactly understand by what you mean when you say *your own comparator*. If you want to make the comparison yourself you could do something like so:

```
public boolean areTheSame(Object arg1, Object arg2)
{
    if (arg1.getClass() != arg0.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    boolean same = true;
    //LOG: Comparing ((A) arg0).getId1() with arg1.id1
    if (((A) arg0).getId1() == arg1.id1) {
        //LOG: Property Id1 is the same for both: Value of Id1 = arg1.id1        
    }
    else {
        //LOG: Property Id1 is not the same. Source Id1 = ((A) arg0).getId1() , target Id1 = arg1.id1
        same = false;
    }

    if (((A) arg0).getId2() == arg1.id2) {
        //LOG: Property Id2 is the same for both: Value of Id2 = this.id2        
    }

    else {
        //LOG: Property Id2 is not the same. Source Id2 = (((A) arg0).getId2(), target Id2 = arg1.id2
        same = false;
    }

    //
    return same;
}
```

You could throw this in your main class and call it instead of these lines:

```
if (obj1.equals(obj2)) {
    System.out.println("EQUALS");
} else {
    System.out.println("NOT EQUALS");
}
```

So you just do:

```
if (areTheSame(obj1, obj2)) 
{
    System.out.println("They are equal");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("They are not equal");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if i want to check the differences with my own comparator, how i can do this. Please advise me on this.

Comment: @Dhruthi: Isn't the overriden implementation of the `equals` method within your class `A` your own comparator?

Comment: Hi npinti, I have a requirement to find the differences of 2 objects which is of same instance using my own comparator(which has to take two arbitrary objects and find the differences and show the result in logging) . I have done it using the equlas(). But i don't remember how i can go with my own comparator class. Please adviseme on this.

Comment: @Dhruthi: I tried to change my answer, this should let you build your *own* comparator which takes in 2 objects. On the other hand, you could merge the answer I provided with the one provided by **Keppil**.

Comment: Thanks for all the reply's here. After comparing how i can show the results in logging format(something in a Audit Trial Format or logging format). Whether i have to use here java.util.logging.Logger or is their any way. Please advise.

Comment: @Dhruthi There are a myriad of Loggers available, such as `Log4J` and `Slf4J` besides the one you mention. You will need to search online to find the one which best suits your need.

Comment: Hi all Thanks for the reply. Is their any API to show this result in an Audit Trial format. I have searched in google but their Audit Trial implemented using Hibernate Interceptor(Its been saving in Database). In my requirement i have to show the differences of the 2 objects using the Audit Trial. ie I want to track the audit trail information of each object differences. Please advise me on this. Thanks.

Comment: @Dhruthi: I would recommend you ask another question since what you are asking seems to be out of scope here. Also, if any of the answers solved the problem you posted, you should mark whatever answered you deem to be correct.

Comment: Hinpinti. Thanks. As of now half of my requirement i have implemented using the above advise. I will post one more with the new topic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *Apache Commons EqualsBuilder* to generate your `equals()` method

Given a class:

```
public class Person {
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Your equals method will look like

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof Person)) {
        return false;
    }
    Person rhs = (Person) object;
    return new EqualsBuilder()
        .appendSuper(super.equals(object))
        .append(firstName, rhs.firstName)
        .append(lastName, rhs.lastName)
        .isEquals();
}
```

Or if you want doing this using reflexion

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use open source tool javers - https://github.com/javers/javers. In Javers you can find method compare(Object one, Object another) with return Diff. Diff contains a List of changes (reference add, property change etc.).